# @react-native-community/netinfo release build fail

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

While I am making a release build in "react-native": "0.62.2" and "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.3"
Any help would be appreciated.
I am getting this error.[image]

Comment: downgrading netinfo to ```5.9.2``` can help

Comment: still not working @MUHAMMADILYAS

Comment: is debug build running?

Comment: Yes perfectly working in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: delete build folder `android -> app -> build`

step 2: run android studio as an admin access

**Other Solution**
remove and reinstall `node_modules`